# $crate::_typed_stream giving errors in compilation with Rocket.rs EventStream! macro

Tags: rust

With Rust, code that worked great now gives this error:

```
error[E0178]: expected a path on the left-hand side of `+`, not `$crate::__typed_stream! {
                  $crate :: response :: stream :: EventStream, $crate :: response :: stream
                  :: stream, $crate :: futures :: stream :: Stream, ::rocket :: response ::
                  stream :: Event
              }`
  --> src\main.rs:36:64
   |
36 | async fn server(q: &State<Sender<Sesion>>, mut t: Shutdown) -> EventStream![]{
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected a path
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::_typed_stream` which comes from the expansion of the macro `EventStream` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: expected expression, found `+`
  --> src\main.rs:38:5
   |
38 | /     EventStream! {

57 | |     }
   | |     ^
   | |     |
   | |_____expected expression
   |       in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::_typed_stream` which comes from the expansion of the macro `EventStream` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

typed_stream macro:

```
macro_rules! _typed_stream {
    ($S:ident, $($t:tt)*) => (
        $crate::__typed_stream! {
            $crate::response::stream::$S,
            $crate::response::stream::stream,
            $crate::futures::stream::Stream,
            $($t)*
        }
    )
}
```

EventStream macro:

```
    macro_rules! EventStream {
        () => ($crate::_typed_stream!(EventStream, $crate::response::stream::Event));
        ($($s:tt)*) => ($crate::_typed_stream!(EventStream, $($s)*));
    }
}
```

minimal example of the main code:

```
use rocket::response::stream::{EventStream};

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/server")]
fn server() -> EventStream![]{
    EventStream! {
    }
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _{
    rocket::build()
    .mount("/", routes![server])
}
```

cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "JJW"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
json = "0.12.4"
rocket = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["json"]}
```

That happened after installing LLVM and having troubles with rust-analyser, y unninstalled both Rust and LLVM, just to reinstall Rust alone, also tried a snapshot of my code that i knew it worked and still gives me that error, even if before the same code worked.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your target directory (`cargo clean`)?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the latest Rust version?

Comment: Yes, i reinstalled directly from the page

Comment: cargo clean seems to make it work, i will test it more and confirm it

Comment: Cargo clean did fixed it, thanks, i was stuck with this and didnt know about that command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems like cargo clean did the trick.